# Nexenta - unknown trap type 8 in user mode

Tags: zfs, opensolaris, nexenta

I'm trying to install NexentaStor 3.1.4.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS KVM on AMD64 platform. During the install I encounter the following exception :

"unknown trap type 8 in user mode"

Can anyone point me what can be the issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a supported setup.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has to do with the Solaris kernel version and patchset that is on NexentaStor 3.x (I don't think you'll see this on 4.x+ once it is released, though don't quote me - I think it still says it, but then boots anyway).

I've had a heck of a time keeping KVM VM's of NexentaStor stable, it isn't presently supported on the 3.x line by Nexenta themselves -- but all the ones that are have '-no-acpi' set. The command line set that I last used that worked (on 3.1.1 I believe), was (and it has been awhile since I tried this) included these: -no-acpi -nographic -no-kvm-irqchip .

Answer (score 0):

had this error on a vm after setting the RAM to the OS recommended minimum of 800.  Once I increased it from 800 to 2048, the error disappeared.  problem could be related to not enough RAM